# Configuring non wacom drawing tablet

Tags: xinput, graphics-tablet, xbindkeys, xev, evdev

I am a linux user and I am a total newbie when it comes to input devices and drivers.

I have recently bought xp-pen star 06 tablet

[tablet specifactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drdcR.jpg)

the tablet works poorly with evdev.

The mouse moves with the tablet but also poorly, the pen nip click is not assigned to left click and the tablet buttons are detected as a keyboard, I have searched and I've found that I can use xev and xbindkeys to remap buttons but I am not sure how.

Any help to configure the tablet will be appreciated

> lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 28bd:0078
```

> xinput

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1010:00 04F3:3012 Touchpad            id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Logitech Wheel Mouse                 id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ XP-PEN STAR 06                            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ XP-PEN STAR 06                            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ E8:07:BF:04:71:B6                         id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

> xinput list-props 11

```
Device 'XP-PEN STAR 06':
    Device Enabled (141):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (277): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (278):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (279):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (280):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (268):    10429, 120
    Device Node (267):  "/dev/input/event2"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (281): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (282):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (283):  0
    Axis Labels (284):  "Abs X" (274), "Abs Y" (275), "Abs Pressure" (276)
    Button Labels (285):    "Button Left" (144), "Button Middle" (145), "Button Right" (146), "Button Wheel Up" (147), "Button Wheel Down" (148), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (149), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (150), "Button Side" (270), "Button Extra" (271), "Button Forward" (272), "Button Back" (310), "Button Task" (311), "Button 8" (308), "Button 9" (309), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (286): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (287):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (288):  50
    Evdev Middle Button Button (289):   2
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (290): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (291): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (292):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (293):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (294):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (295):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (296):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (297):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (298): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (299):  0
```

> xinput list-props 12

```
Device 'XP-PEN STAR 06':
    Device Enabled (141):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (143): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (277): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (278):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (279):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (280):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (268):    10429, 120
    Device Node (267):  "/dev/input/event1"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (281): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (282):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (283):  0
    Axis Labels (284):  "Abs X" (274), "Abs Y" (275), "Abs Pressure" (276), "Rel Vert Wheel" (273)
    Button Labels (285):    "Button Left" (144), "Button Middle" (145), "Button Right" (146), "Button Wheel Up" (147), "Button Wheel Down" (148), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (149), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (150), "Button Side" (270), "Button Extra" (271), "Button Forward" (272), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269), "Button Unknown" (269)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (286): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (287):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (288):  50
    Evdev Middle Button Button (289):   2
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (290): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (291): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (292):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (293):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (294):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (295):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (296):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (297):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (298): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (299):  0
```

> xinput get-button-map 11

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

> xinput get-button-map 12

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

xev pen tip click:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 7430718, (111,141), root:(2064,202),
    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 7430782, (111,141), root:(2064,202),
    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES
```

xev pen buttons:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 7517367, (86,133), root:(2039,194),
    state 0x10, button 9, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 7517611, (86,133), root:(2039,194),
    state 0x10, button 9, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 7518335, (86,133), root:(2039,194),
    state 0x10, button 10, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 7518499, (86,133), root:(2039,194),
    state 0x10, button 10, same_screen YES
```